# RxJava2 Difference between as(), to() and compose()

Tags: rx-java2

These words are difficult to search online, so I can't find any information on them besides the docs, which seems to me to have almost the same description (specially for `as` and `to`).

What's the difference between `as()`, `to()` and `compose()` in RxJava2? When should I use any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to` and `as` are practically the same. The difference is that `to` uses the more broad `Function` interface and `as` uses the dedicated `XConverter` interface. The former can't be implemented for multiple reactive types. [Issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5654), [PR](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5729).

The difference between `to`/`as` and `compose` is that the former lets you turn the sequence into arbitrary result type during assembly time whereas the latter can only turn into the same reactive type but possibly different type argument(s).

Comment: So just to be clear `to`/`as` can turn a `Single<String>` into an `Integer` and `compose` can turn a `Single<String>` into a `Single<Person>`?